# Customizing 'Item Saved' message in custom component

Tags: database, view, model, controller

I'm trying to find a way to customize the message displayed after a successful record has been saved in a custom component. Well not really the entire message, just the 'item' part. For instance if my component is titled Resources, I'd like the success message to display, 'resource saved' rather than 'item saved'. And in the list view when it displays: 'N_ITEMS_CHECKED_IN' I would also like to replace the 'ITEMS' part. I know I could just interpret this in the language file. But I would still like to know how to change it.

I know the `$text_prefix` variable in the `AdminModel` controls the prefix. I looked for something similar in the Joomla core files, but I couldn't find anything. Or maybe I just didn't look in the correct place.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue. You already know you can use a custom prefix if your model extends `Joomla\CMS\MVC\Model\AdminModel`. Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: I guess I don't know how to use a custom prefix then. Because setting `$text_prefix` doesn't replace the message 'item saved', even though it says it's used with controller messages. I've looked at `Joomla\CMS\MVC\Model\AdminModel` and none of the variables correspond with replacing 'item' on messages. You're saying I can create a custom prefix to allow this?

Comment: What value did you try for `$text_prefix`?

Comment: I just put a language string that translates to the name of my component. In looking at other examples, that's how I've always seen it used. For instance, in this case I put `COM_REPORTS`. And in my language file I translate it to the official name of my component. This does get translated and rendered in various location in the component. However, it doesn't replace the 'item saved' text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Joomla\CMS\MVC\Model\FormModel::$text_prefix` property is used to define a prefix used for building language keys throughout the model. It defaults to component's element (e.g. `COM_REPORTS`). This would result in a language key like `COM_REPORTS_N_ITEMS_CHECKED_IN`. To use multiple strings per component, use different suffixes per model, e.g. `COM_REPORTS_RESOURCES` in one model (which would result in a key like `COM_REPORTS_RESOURCES_N_ITEMS_CHECKED_IN` ) and `COM_REPORTS_SOMEOTHERITEMS` in another model. And add the appropriate language strings to language files.

You should note that `Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\FormController` also has `$text_prefix` property which is used the same way. This is where the generic "Item saved" string comes from. They key by default would be `COM_REPORTS_SAVE_SUCCESS` but you can change it by changing the prefix.

Comment: Thank you!! The controller's `$text_prefix` property and the `_SAVE_SUCCESS` key was what I needed. I had never changed that property in the controller, only in the model.